# Calling new on the db string name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so i have the string "Product".

```
table_name = "Product"
```

I cant do

```
table_name.new

undefined method `new
```

So i was trying to find a work around like this

```
table_name = table_name.downcase.pluralize
name = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.select { |t| t == table_name }.first
name.new
```

I am not sure this will work but even if it does it looks like a hack, any ideas to clean this up

Comment: figured it out 

eval "instance = #{table_name}.new"

Comment: I would suggest using constantize instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid calling `eval` you can also do

`"product".camelize.constantize.new`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(instance_eval table_name).new
```